# Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xmppframework

I am using `XMPPFramework` in my application. I have imported the Cocoa/Cocoa.h in my .m file. But when i build the project `Xcode` shows an error.

> error: "Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found".

How can i solve this Error?

Answer (score 12):

If you're building for iOS then you *shouldn't* `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`. That header only exists on OS X. For iOS you need to include the various framework headers directly (e.g., `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`).

Answer (score 4):

Add this line :

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

remove this :

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

put 
`#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"` **or** `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` in your .m file

And Alos i don't like **Copy and Paste** , so please refer this Question/Answer
[Cocoa/Cocoa.h Not Found (Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530819/cocoa-cocoa-h-not-found-error)
It is similar to your Question.

Comment: The latter is the better choice -- angle brackets for system headers.

Comment: #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> is already in my .m file. but still this error occurring. By the way the link u provided dont give any help.
thanks.